# Elasticsearch dynamic templating

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, mapping

I'm trying to get ES's (using I'm using ES v1.4.1) dynamic templating to work on my local machine and for some reason the `"mappings"` are not being included? I first create the index with a simple

```
PUT /bigtestindex (I'm using Sense plugin, not curl),
```

then I follow that with

```
PUT /_template/bigtestindex_1
{
  "template": "big*",
  "settings": {
   "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 1   
   },
   "analysis": {
      "filter": {
         "autocomplete_filter": {
            "type": "edge_ngram",
            "min_gram": "1",
            "max_gram": "20",
            "token_chars": [
              "letter",
              "digit"
              ]
         }
      },
      "analyzer": {
         "autocomplete": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "filter": [
               "lowercase",
               "asciifolding",
               "autocomplete_filter"
            ]     
        },
        "whitespace_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
            ]
          }
        }
       },
      "mappings": {
       "doc": {
          "properties": {
             "anchor": {
                "type": "string"
             },
             "boost": {
                "type": "string"
             },
             "content": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
             },
             "digest": {
                "type": "string"
             },
             "host": {
                "type": "string"
             },
             "id": {
                "type": "string"
             },
             "metatag.description": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "standard"
             },
             "metatag.keywords": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "standard"
             },
             "segment": {
                "type": "string"
             },
             "title": {
             "type": "string",
             "index": "not_analyzed",
             "fields": {
                  "autocomplete": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index_analyzer": "autocomplete",
                  "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
                }
              }
            },
             "tstamp": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "dateOptionalTime"
             },
             "url": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I'm not receiving any errors and the syntax looks to be correct but when I do something like

```
GET /bigtestindex/_mappings
```

in Sense, I get

```
    {
   "bigtestindex": {
      "mappings": {}
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my Sense command was a bit off, should have been

```
PUT /bigtestindex/_template/bigtesttemplate_1 (creates index and template in one command
```

OR

```
PUT /_template/bigtesttemplate_1  (creates just template) thanks to @avr for pointing out my incorrect command (needed some fresh eyes)
```

instead of

```
PUT /bigtestindex/_template/bigtesttemplate_1
```

discovered this after trying several things, hth someone else

UPDATE
As @avr stated, you do need to create the template first and then the index, you can create the index and the template in the same PUT statement as well.

It has everything to do with making sure your `JSON` is setup properly to match the right API endpoints. "mappings" should be separate from settings i.e.

```
{
"settings" {
...
},
 "mappings" {
...
 }
}
```

NOT

```
{
"settings" {
...
"mappings" {
 }
}

"mappings" should NOT be included in the `"settings"` - needs to be separate.
```

hth, anyone else having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create template then create index. You can find the same from elasticsearch documentation.

> Templates are only applied at index creation time. Changing a template will have no impact on existing indices.

Comment: yes you are correct, however - it doesn't solve the problem - but that is the correct order of actions to take

Comment: it has more to do with how you have the json setup to match the proper API endpoints.

Comment: What do you mean by _it doesn't solve the probelm_ ? I don't think there exists an API end point with `template` !

Comment: your solution was correct in terms of template creation, but it didn't solve the mappings issue. If you look at the JSON posted in the question, I'm trying to create autocomplete within the template. The mappings issue was solved with proper JSON structure within the template

Comment: ohh.. I din't observed that and its tough too find that :) . But your answer is misleading and correct command to use for template creation is `PUT /_template/bigtesttemplate_1` NOT `PUT /template/bigtesttemplate_1`